# Azure function to orchestrate the functions in other functions app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to make an azure function that can orchestrate 2 other azure functions in different function apps.
Let us suppose we have function1(HTTP Trigger) in functionapp1 in python and function2(HTTP trigger) in PowerShell in functionapp2.

I want to make an azure function function3 in functionapp3 which can run both functions.

There is a concept of durable functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=python

But I think, it only works with functions in same function app.

**Is there any way to do that? If yes how?**

Comment: Since they are http triggered isn't it just a matter of sending an http request? I am not sure what difficulty you have.

Comment: Call the http APIs using Python from function 3 in whatever sequence you need.

Comment: I think your easiest way it to use a LogicApp for the orchestration.

Comment: @peter bons I want to do orchestration. Like to run one function after other.

Comment: I still don't see any issue. Just call them in sequence. You need to share more of the inner workings if you think just making some http calls is not going to work for you.

Comment: I know there is the concept of durable functions but it works when are working with all the functions are in only the same function app but we are using different function apps.

Comment: But why is just calling the endpoints in the right order not sufficient? Please give us more details to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below steps helps to workaround:

**It all depends on your requirements (inner workings).**

- If you need to **directly** call another function, you can use the **HTTP protocol** and send your **request** to the endpoint of the other function.
- In case it is **indirect** or **asynchronous** you can choose to use a queue. Refer the **[best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices?tabs=csharp#cross-function-communication) for cross-functionality of Azure Functions.**

For Cross function communication (calling one function app from another function app), it is better to use **Durable Functions** and **Azure Logic Apps** that are built to manage communication between multiple functions and state transitions.

**Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/performance-reliability#cross-function-communication) for more information.**